# Advice on polling for new documents in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I want to poll for new documents in my Raven DB. What is the recommended way of doing this? Can I use the IndexTimestamp or can I rely on the order of the documents?

I guess I want to either do it in two steps: 
1. Check if there is anything new, if so:
  1.1. Get the latest X documents.

Or in one step: Get the latest X documents and have it return those or tell me that there's nothing new according some argument I sent.

FYI: I have no corresponding CLR objects to the documents.

Comment: LinusK,
You might want to look and see how we do this with the smuggler utility.
It is explicitly doing exactly what you want, getting the latest documents since the one last seen.
The code for that is here:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Smuggler/Smuggler.cs

Comment: Is your architecture such that you are forced to poll the database? Another approach you can take is to listen to write events in the database and take action on that.

Answer (score 1):

I would not poll for it, but I would use the Changes API included with RavenDB to just get the continuous stream of documents from RavenDB.

Check out the Changes API here http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/changes-api

I personally would use the Changes API with some kind of Message Bus (RabbitMQ) to make sure every change is processed and resilient.

If you still want to poll, just create an index with your date time and sort in descending order.

```
var result = session.Query<Orders>()
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList();
```

If you need to process every document, you might want to create marker documents that include the id of the document you get and make sure they have not been processed.

To do that:

```
marker id : polling/processed/order/1
```

Index:

```
from o in orders
let processed = LoadDocument("polling/processed/" + o.Id)
select new {
   WasProcessed = processed != null,
   Created = o.Created
}
```

A few options for you, hope that helps :)